# Refresh JTable data after updating database

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable

I have a JTable that I created with the Netbeans GUI creator and populated the table by using Vector objects. I want the table to be updated after a change is made to the database. I'm not sure how to do this. Could anyone please guide me through doing this?

Comment: See [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to put this after your update code

rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Table order by columnName");
table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));



//Create function

private TableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    // names of columns

        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

        for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {

            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));

        }

        // data of the table

        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

        while (rs.next()) {

            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();

            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {

                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));

            }

            data.add(vector);

        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }
```